# PHP detect string words

Tags: php

I have some code that takes the url and put's it into a variable, then i have another line of code that takes everything in the url after the "?" and put that into a string and finally i have ANOTHER variable that takes everything behind the SECOND "?" from the url. Example:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$query_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$query_string2 = parse_url($query_string, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

This is an example of what the URL looks like:

> http://localhost/index.php?skap?1

and then i have some code that check's the url using those variable, and if it finds "skap" in the url, it should execute some code, and if not, don't execute the code.

```
<?php if ($query_string == "skap"): ?>
```

The problem here is that i check's the full url after the first "?", so it get's "skap?1" and there for it dosent execute the code.
Though my website is built so that i have a series of links so i can the the url to be either "skap?1" "skap?2" and so on up untill "skap?14".

What should i do to make it so the if statment checks if "skap" is in the url, and if it sees it it executes the code, and ignores anything else, so if it's "skap?8" or only "skap" dosen't matter, as long as it can find "skap" it should execute the code.

Comment: Strpos seems like a good tool for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use preg_match.  preg_match does not care what prefix or suffix there might be.  If it matches anywere, it will return true.

```
$url = "http://localhost/index.php?skap?1";
$query_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
if (preg_match('/skap/',$query_string))
{
    echo "Run code!";
}
else
{
    echo "Do NOT run code!";
}
```

Comment: preg_match would also find matches in path or (sub)domain. What about strpos combined with explode?

Comment: @Kapparina: quite right, thanks for pointing it out, I modified my answer.

Comment: Sorry, strpos alone would to the exact same thing, if used on the complete request uri. Using parse_url like OP is a good idea imho.

Answer (score 0):

here is the reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
$pos = strpos($query_string, 'skap');
if ($pos === false) {
    //The string 'skap' was not found in the string '$query_string'
} else {
    // The string 'skap' was found in the string '$query_string'"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, take an url like this:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/index.php?skap?1&erer&hh=1';
```

This would match your requirements.

Parsing the url using parse_url gives you this:

```
$components = parse_url($url);
var_dump($components);
array(2) { 
    ["path"]=> string(21) "/index.php" 
    ["query"]=> string(16) "skap?1&erer&hh=1" 
}
```

Then check if the string `skap` exists in `$components['query']` at all, e.g. like this:

```
if (strpos($component['query'] !== false) {
    // it was found, do something
}
```

Check like this instead if 'skap' is supposed to be at the beginning of the string:

```
if (strpos($component['query'] === 0) {
    // it was found at string's beginning, do something
}
```

Hope this helps.
(I know you already used parse_url, but I thought a complete answer would be better.)

Answer (score 0):

Using explode on "?" and removing the domain and page from the url we can then use in_array to see if the word "skap" is there.

```
$url = ["http://localhost/index.php?skap?1",
        "http://localhost/skap.php?flap?1"];

Foreach($url as $val){
    If(skap($val)){
        Echo "run code \n";
    }Else{
        Echo "don't run \n";
    }
}

Function skap($url){
    $arr = explode("?", $url);
    Unset($arr[0]); // remove url domain and page name

    If(in_array("skap", $arr)){
        Return true;
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
run code 
don't run
```

https://3v4l.org/9Xdpk